Is a broom without a long handle still called a broom?
Dictionaries say a broom has a long handle. But if a broom doesn't have a long handle and people have to bend down to sweep, is such a broom still called a broom?




What dictionaries use the word "must"?  And "long" is a relative term.  That handle is much longer than the handle of a whisk broom, and shorter than the handle of the kind of broom that allows the typical adult user to stand upright.

The essence of a broom are its gathered bristles and some way for it to be held in the hand(s), either by an attached handle or via the bristles themselves.

@TimR - Cambridge Dictionary, Merriam-Webster, Collins Dictionary, Oxford Learner's Dictionaries, Dictionary.com, all say that a broom is a brush with a long handle, but that does not allow for regional variations.

@MichaelHarvey OP's original question before it was edited had the phrase "must have a long handle".

@TimR - we don't have 'whisk brooms' where I live; is it an American thing?

@MichaelHarvey  Sure you do.  Your butler or valet uses one when brushing the shoulders of your jacket.

Where I live a broom is a brush with a long handle that you can use to sweep the floor without bending. With a short handle it's just a 'brush', sometimes you get a little set called a 'dustpan and brush' that kind of live together. But in Bristol a broom is a 'sweeping brush'.

Where did you find those photos? Those types of brooms made with  straw or sorghum are very old-fashioned, they would be used outside, in a courtyard/ backyard or whereever the ground is paved. They're great for sweeping dirt, stray leaves, twigs and the like. I don't know anyone who would use it on a carpet,  I have very house-proud aunts, aged 90+, who use normal brooms between hooverings.

@Mari-LouA Such a thing for sweeping floor is rather popular in Russia. It's called "веник ['venik]" in Russian. You may look at its photos here: veniks, people with a venik.

@MichaelHarvey We like to condemn question-posters for failure to google; did you try googling "whisk broom"?

@AndyBonner - I was deliberately making the point that it is not a universally known, everyday word for a little brush.

I'm going to guess that you're right that there's regionality at work, because as far as I was aware it is.

Unfortunately any "what do you can this" question is going to prove controversial. It's a good job you didn't show a photo of a bread bun.

What's stunning to me is how unaware we all are of this variability, and how few answers have said "it's complicated" and how many have said "it's definitely this or that, and I'm sure it's universal." I mean, I know about lorry/truck and lift/elevator, but I had no idea about this.

Few Anglophones would balk if the caption to the photo of the woman in the green dress said something like "Woman with rustic broom".
Definitions in dictionaries are not specifications.  Moreover, like IQ tests, they have their social,  economic, regional, and cultural biases.
The essence of a broom are its gathered bristles and some way for it to be held in the hand(s).  Some brooms are designed to be pushed, some to be pulled, some  to be held in one hand and used in a back-and-forth or side-to-side sweeping motion, and some brooms fall somewhere in-between.

I don't know about 'gathered bristles'. Where I live, the bristles of brooms are short and rammed into rows of holes in a bar of wood, in the middle of which is a larger hole designed to take a wooden 'broomstick', which can be bought at many hardware stores, and which can also be used for hoes and other garden tools. Those things with gathered bristles which witches fly on in children's books are another type of broom, specifically besoms.

@MichaelHarvey I would consided that a form of gathering, though an industrial one.

@MichaelHarvey besom describes the brooms shown in the OP but I don't think children use them often. The OP's picures are all short-handled, but my dictionary link shows a long-handled one (which a witch would need).

'Rustic broom' describes it, but that's not what it's called. Like saying something is an "antique clock" - 100 years ago it was just a clock.

@Astralbee It's called a broom. In other words, "broom" is not a misnomer. A whisk broom is a broom.  A push-broom is a broom. A besom broom is a broom. To say it's not a broom is like saying "That's not a chair. It's a desk chair".

As you said, the definition of a 'broom' is a brush with a long handle. If it doesn't have a long handle then it would simply be called a brush, a sweeping brush, or maybe a duster (although these are normally made of softer material than bristled brooms).
The brush in your photographs is a bit unusual - not long enough to be useful as a broom for sweeping but too long to be useful as a hand-held brush. Just look at the two users - they are bent double! If I had to make up a name for such a brush I'd call it a back-breaker (joke).
Interestingly this kind of brush, along with its counterpart, is called a dustpan and brush:
And, overwhelmingly, shopping sites call this a long-handled dustpan and brush:
So it would seem that, regardless of how long the handle is, when it is part of a combo like this it is called a brush. And, as that is how it being used in your example photos, I'd stick with that.
Note: There are always some items that have multiple names and these can vary between English-speaking regions and dialects. My point of view is as a native British English speaker with connections to both the north and south of the country. I also consulted a native US English speaker for input. I believe what I've presented here is a majority view but there may be a host of variations from others.

When I first came to live in Bristol, UK (from London, 120 miles away), I was struck by how the locals called what I knew as a 'broom',  a 'brush'.

I'd call that brush in the pictures a kind of short-handled 'besom'. You used to see them (with long handles) in Westerns.

Definitely "broom and dustpan" for me. The kind with the horizontal handle is definitely a brush, but that's not the first thing I'd think of for use with a dustpan.

https://www.lowes.com/pd/Marshalltown-9-in-Poly-Fiber-Multi-surface-All-purpose-Whisk-Broom-6-Pack/5013023169

I'd suggest moving the "ymmv" disclaimer to the top, and I don't know that it can even claim (universal) majority. For me (US), if it's for sweeping the floor, it's a "broom," regardless of its handle. It may be called a "whisk" rather than a "whisk broom," but that's understood as an omission. Brushes are for teeth, paint, hair, etc. For me, googling "whisk broom" yields many items for sale, like the Lowes listing above, though Google probably selects these results regionally.

Google, for me, with the AI labs feature turned on, inserts the definition "Whisk brooms, also called hand brooms, are compact and versatile tools that are ideal for spot cleaning and hard-to-reach areas. They have a small brush head and a short handle, making them easy to handle and store." It derives it from this page: https://www.webstaurantstore.com/guide/548/types-of-brooms.html

@AndyBonner why don't people just ask AI in the first place instead of coming here for input from actual native speakers?

@Astralbee I'm not sure whether you're suggesting that the result should be ignored, and I'm certainly against AI use on SE, and have my concerns about it in general. But note that the text is lifted from a retail web page that lists "whisk brooms" under "types of brooms."

No. A short corn broom like the ones pictured is called a whisk (or whisk broom). A short plastic bristly one, often but not always with a handle perpendicular to the bristles, is called a brush.

My whisk is made of wire, and makes my hot milk frothy.

I've Googled 'whisk brooms' and they have short handles. They seem like an old-fashioned version of what you would use with a modern dustpan and call a 'brush'. I don't believe that's what is in the OP's photo.

@Astralbee Not only is it what I call it in my part of the world, but when I Google it, the photos match the OP's (and your description) pretty exactly. They can also be bought locally at a housewares store here, old-fashioned though they may be. MichaelHarvey Yes, there is more than one meaning.

I don't see that the material is (heh) material to the designation. There are plenty of synthetic-fiber "brooms."

@AndyBonner True. I was thinking of this kind of thing as opposed to the corn ones shown in the OP's question.

@Astralbee, this is exactly what the term whisk broom conjures up for me.

The lady is using the patented Mega-Whisker™
